# Ошибка при упаковке проекта maven: launch4j.BuilderException

Tags: java, maven

Есть у меня проект, написанный на java, в основном, с использованием javafx. Проблема в том, что, пытаясь упаковать его в .exe (нужен именно экзешник), получаю такую ошибку:

```
 [ERROR]
    net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException: net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): C:\Users\Михаил\.m2\repository\com\aka
    thist\maven\plugins\launch4j\launch4j-maven-plugin\1.5.1\launch4j-maven-plugin-1.5.1-workdir-win32\bin\windres.exe --pre
    processor=type -J rc -O coff -F pe-i386 C:\Users\8FEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j7244992626989978492rc C:\Users\8FEE~1
    \AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j4703142106425399337o
            at net.sf.launch4j.Builder.build(Builder.java:144)
            at com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j.Launch4jMojo.execute(Launch4jMojo.java:353)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.
    java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): C:\Users\Михаил\.m2\repository\com\akathist\maven\plugins\lau
    nch4j\launch4j-maven-plugin\1.5.1\launch4j-maven-plugin-1.5.1-workdir-win32\bin\windres.exe --preprocessor=type -J rc -O
     coff -F pe-i386 C:\Users\8FEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j7244992626989978492rc C:\Users\8FEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\lau
    nch4j4703142106425399337o
            at net.sf.launch4j.Util.exec(Util.java:148)
            at net.sf.launch4j.Cmd.exec(Builder.java:205)
            at net.sf.launch4j.Builder.build(Builder.java:97)
            ... 22 more
```

вот build блок моего .pom файла:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.ediagent.edi.gui.Main</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-clui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <jar>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}-shaded.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>${project.build.directory}/hasCode.exe</outfile>
                            <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>com.ediagent.edi.gui.Main</mainClass>
                                <preCp>anything</preCp>
                            </classPath>
                            <icon>src/main/resources/icon/edisoft_ediagent_new_logo.png</icon>
                            <jre>
                                <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                            </jre>
                            <versionInfo>
                                <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                                <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                                <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                                <copyright>2012 hasCode.com</copyright>
                                <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                                <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                                <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                                <companyName>edisoft.ru</companyName>
                                <internalName>ediagent</internalName>
                                <originalFilename>ediagent.exe</originalFilename>
                            </versionInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Опыта по использованию мавена для создания экзешников у меня нет, и pom  написан по сомнительным образцам, так что извиняюсь, если он в корне неверен. Я знаю, что лучше паковать java проекты в jar, но на выходе нужен именно экзешник, так что, буду признателен, если кто-то сможет указать на ошибки, или ткнуть носом в толковый мануал. К критике отношусь номально и готов.